# using library in python giving warnings i can't turn off

Tags: python, numpy

I wish to use this library:
https://pypi.org/project/rampy/

> import rampy as rp

But then I get lots of warnings, how could I turn them off? I can't figure it out.

> /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/least_angle.py:30:
> DeprecationWarning: `np.float` is a deprecated alias for the builtin
> `float`. To silence this warning, use `float` by itself. Doing this
> will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted
> the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here. Deprecated in NumPy
> 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
> method='lar', copy_X=True, eps=np.finfo(np.float).eps,
> /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/least_angle.py:167:
> DeprecationWarning: `np.float` is a deprecated alias for the builtin
> `float`. To silence this warning, use `float` by itself. Doing this
> will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted
> the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here. Deprecated in NumPy
> 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
> method='lar', copy_X=True, eps=np.finfo(np.float).eps,
> /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/least_angle.py:284:
> DeprecationWarning: `np.float` is a deprecated alias for the builtin
> `float`. To silence this warning, use `float` by itself. Doing this
> will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted
> the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here. Deprecated in NumPy
> 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
> eps=np.finfo(np.float).eps, copy_Gram=True, verbose=0,
> /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/least_angle.py:862:
> DeprecationWarning: `np.float` is a deprecated alias for the builtin
> `float`. To silence this warning, use `float` by itself. Doing this
> will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted
> the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here. Deprecated in NumPy
> 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
> eps=np.finfo(np.float).eps, copy_X=True, fit_path=True,
> /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/least_angle.py:1101:
> DeprecationWarning: `np.float` is a deprecated alias for the builtin
> `float`. To silence this warning, use `float` by itself. Doing this
> will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted
> the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here. Deprecated in NumPy
> 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
> eps=np.finfo(np.float).eps, copy_X=True, fit_path=True,
> /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/least_angle.py:1127:
> DeprecationWarning: `np.float` is a deprecated alias for the builtin
> `float`. To silence this warning, use `float` by itself. Doing this
> will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted
> the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here. Deprecated in NumPy
> 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
> eps=np.finfo(np.float).eps, positive=False):
> /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/least_angle.py:1362:
> DeprecationWarning: `np.float` is a deprecated alias for the builtin
> `float`. To silence this warning, use `float` by itself. Doing this
> will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted
> the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here. Deprecated in NumPy
> 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
> max_n_alphas=1000, n_jobs=None, eps=np.finfo(np.float).eps,
> /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/least_angle.py:1602:
> DeprecationWarning: `np.float` is a deprecated alias for the builtin
> `float`. To silence this warning, use `float` by itself. Doing this
> will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted
> the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here. Deprecated in NumPy
> 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
> max_n_alphas=1000, n_jobs=None, eps=np.finfo(np.float).eps,
> /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/least_angle.py:1738:
> DeprecationWarning: `np.float` is a deprecated alias for the builtin
> `float`. To silence this warning, use `float` by itself. Doing this
> will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted
> the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here. Deprecated in NumPy
> 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
> eps=np.finfo(np.float).eps, copy_X=True, positive=False):
> /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/online_lda.py:29:
> DeprecationWarning: `np.float` is a deprecated alias for the builtin
> `float`. To silence this warning, use `float` by itself. Doing this
> will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted
> the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here. Deprecated in NumPy
> 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations   EPS
> = np.finfo(np.float).eps /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/gradient_boosting.py:32:
> DeprecationWarning: `np.bool` is a deprecated alias for the builtin
> `bool`. To silence this warning, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will
> not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the
> numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here. Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for
> more details and guidance:
> https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
> from ._gradient_boosting import predict_stages
> /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/gradient_boosting.py:32:
> DeprecationWarning: `np.bool` is a deprecated alias for the builtin
> `bool`. To silence this warning, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will
> not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the
> numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here. Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for
> more details and guidance:
> https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
> from ._gradient_boosting import predict_stages

Comment: You can probably use the [warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) module to silence them (selectively). Alternatively, you could downgrade NumPy to a version with those deprecation warnings (not recommended).

Comment: Those warnings are coming from scikit-learn, and occur because of change in numpy 1.20.  You might be able to eliminate them if you upgrade to the latest version of scikit-learn.

Comment: Thank you all! updating scikit-learn worked!!!